# Rails3 not rendering page correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a simple Rails3 application running in a sub URL that works well except for one problem. If I do not add a ".html" extension at the end of a URL for the "index" method of any of the controllers, the request returns a blank page. It does not matter which controller I request, the "index" method always returns completely empty, including if I curl the URL. I have an "index.html.erb" file in each of the controllers, with simple but complete HTML, and if I do include the ".html" extension in the URL, everything works fine. Here are some example URLs and their results:

```
http://my.application.url/appname/pages -- returns a blank page.
http://my.application.url/appname/pages.html -- returns the correct HTML page
http://my.application.url/appname/pages/new -- returns the correct HTML form
http://my.application.url/appname/pages/1 -- returns the correct HTML page
http://my.application.url/appname/pages/1/edit -- returns the correct HTML form
```

My routes file looks similar to this:

```
My::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "/appname" do
    resources :posts
    resources :pages
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
end
```

The applicable part of my controller looks similar to this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
   end
...
end
```

As I said, the index method is the only one that is having this problem. I have tried everything I can think of, including adding `My::Application.default_url_options = {:format => "html"}` in application.rb (which works except when I need to do a redirect_to from the controller), and I am at a loss. The app is using Thin as an application server proxied behind Apache 1.3 (which I unfortunately cannot change, and this doesn't seem to be an issue anyway because hitting the Thin server directly results in the same problem). Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just confirmed that the problem is not Thin. Same problem exists in Webrick

Comment: Not completely an answer (more of a workaround) but removing my [controllername].css.scss files from the assets pipeline fixed the problem. I have used Rails for a number of years but am unfortunately not yet fully familiar with the new asset pipeline in Rails 3. This behavior seems strange and somewhat unintuitive to me, almost as if the "convention over configuration" paradigm is being diluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer seems to be that if the URL does not specify the .html extension, the application will serve out assets (from the asset pipeline) of the same name as the controller, at least while running in the development environment. Once I removed the [controllername].css.scss and [controllername].js.coffee files (both of which were unused anyway) that were auto-generated when I created the controllers from the assets folder, the application worked correctly. Just for kicks, I tried leaving them in and running `rake assets:precompile`, but the behavior persisted until the files were actually removed. This still seems counterintuitive, and I am contemplating filing this as a bug.